# Random file as second parameter in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, random, command-line, parameters, command-prompt

I have one string

> FOR %%A in (SRCdocs\*.doc) DO doc2rtf -f addon\format1.fmt -file
>   "%%A" -out "%%A.rtf"

This string process all source *.doc files in subfolder "SRCdocs", apply ONE FORMAT FILE (format1.fmt from subfolder "addon"). As result, I have all doc files converted to rtf with applying only one format filter (format1.fmt)

I need to edit this line for implementation of applauding random filter for each doc to rtf conversion.

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "count=0"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "addon\*.fmt"^|findstr /n "^"') do (
        set "format[%%a]=%%b"
        set "count=%%a"
    )

    for %%a in ("SRCdocs\*.doc") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set /a "format=!random! %% %count% + 1"
        for %%b in ("!format!") do for %%c in ("!format[%%~b]!") do (
            endlocal
            echo doc2rtf -f "addon\%%~c" -file "%%~fa" -out "%%~fa.rtf"
        )
    )
```

Load the `.fmt` file list in an array in memory. Now, for each of the input `.doc` files select a random element from the list of `.fmt` files.

`doc2rtf` command is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the filename after the -out to be randomized.  I assume thereby something like fred.doc is output to fred12345.rtf.

What you're looking for is the `%RANDOM%` variable, which provides a random number between 0 and 32767.  Because you're in a loop, you further have to use delayed expansion (or you'll get the same number each time--maybe that's okay but I'll assume not).

So your batch file must contain this before your loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

then in your `FOR` statement you'd do this:

```
FOR %%A in (SRCdocs\*.doc) DO doc2rtf -f addon\format1.fmt -file "%%A" -out "%%A!RANDOM!.rtf"
```

If you'd like the same random number for all the files in this particular run, just use `%RANDOM%` instead of `!RANDOM!`.

By the way, it'll be easier to read your code if you use parentheses and split that into multiple lines:

```
FOR %%A in (SRCdocs\*.doc) DO (
    doc2rtf -f addon\format1.fmt -file "%%A" -out "%%A.rtf"
)
```

Not functionally different but I find it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Dear Torqane! Thank you very much! My task is a little bit different. Sorry for my bad English. I need to take random format*.fmt file from the directory "addon" to process it for each converting process. For example - this function have to take first doc-file then apply random format*.fmt file and then output file have to be the same as source doc-file, but converted to rtf. How can I do that? How to apply random filter to convert each file?